# How to pass a function (or expression) into the where clause of an Entity Framework Query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm getting errors when I try and do something like this:

from s in db.SomeDbSet where IsValid(s) select s

It errors telling me that it can't process IsValid.

Basically what I'm trying to do is filter based on another dbSet inside the Where that is linked and does an any, but it won't let me.

I've tried a million different ways of doing a Expression but I can't find the right way and building my own Extension method like Where doesn't seem to work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your IsValid function?

In this case it's EF job to take LINQ syntax and turn it into SQL syntax.
EF can't turn your function into SQL. it only supports a set number of functions that have a clear SQL equivalent commend.

you have two options:

1) Rewrite the function as a series of supported commends. This will be turned into a SQL sub-query, Meaning a single trip to the database, For example:

```
// will only return records that have at least one related entity marked as full.
query.Where(m => m.ReletedEntities.Any(re => re.IsFull == true));
```

2) Get all the data from the database and then using Linq and your function work with the data. this will be done in memory using your actual function that will be called once for every item in the collection. You will also have to load the related entity collection. or it will still be an "entity framework translated to SQL query", And will fail if you use your function.

Comment: Basically the function (or expression) I'm trying to build is trying to do a where based on 3 parameters and return a projection to a known type. (IQueryable<type>)  I was hoping to build my own extension method like Where or Select and do both at the same time in one go to clean up the code and make it Junior-Proof. I was able to do some half-measures but it isn't elegant like a single call would be.

Comment: I think you will have to list the predicts one by one using the where clause. if this was Linq just LINQ you could have created a new method extending IQueryable. but in this case you have to change the EF source code so that it understands your new function. there are two other solution I can offer the first is is creating a stored proc that does the needed filtering and calling it using the data context.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking about a stored proc, but then I'd have to put the whole thing in the stored proc, because it would have the same hit as a TVF if it was called inline. I also considered using a TVF that was a single line so that it could be inlined by the query optimizer, but EF Code First STILL doesn't support them to my knowledge.